# django crud server always return 404

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i tring to create a very simple crud server using django
but i always get 404 not found and i not sure why
i'm shering all my code (hope it's not too long)
glad to your help

here my setting.py

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'leads',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('leads.urls')),
```

leads.serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from leads.models import Lead


class LeadSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = '__all__'
```

leads.urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import LeadViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/leads', LeadViewSet, 'leads')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

my post http request is http://localhost:8000/leads/
with a simple body

Comment: You should use **`http://localhost:8000/api/leads/`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:
`http://localhost:8000/api/leads/`
Because in root URL you don't define URL but in child
you defined `router.register('api/leads', LeadViewSet, 'leads')`

so your endpoint has URL `/api/leads`

Answer (score 0):

What others have said is true. You probably hit a wrong url.

If you want something extra to see what routes/urls you have available, you might want to install [django_extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)

install it with

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'django_extensions',
...
)
```

then you will be able to run

`python manage.py show_urls`

which will show all URLs that are available in your app.